# PostgreSQL finding the 3 most popular articles in a news database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently trying to find the 3 most popular articles in a database. I want to print out the title and amount of views for each. I know I'll have to join two of the tables together (articles & log) in order to do so.

The articles table has a column of the titles, and one with a slug for the title.

The log table has a column of the paths in the format of /article/'slug'.

How would I join these two tables, filter out the path to compare to the slug column of the articles table, and use count to display the number of times it was viewed?

The correct query used was:

```
SELECT title, count(*) as views 
FROM articles a, log l 
WHERE a.slug=substring(l.path, 10) 
GROUP BY title 
ORDER BY views DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: You need to include the table definitions and a better description of what you want, along with what you tried so far. If words fail you to describe the problem clearly, add sample data to show what you need.

Comment: To rephrase Laurenz's comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: The original post has edited with the query that gave me the correct results based on RonaldFindling's help. Thank you!

Comment: Please learn how to use the modern explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient and outdated implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you just need to join two tables based on one column using aggregation. The catch is that you can't compare them directly but have to use some [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) before.

Assuming a schema like this:

```
article
| title  | slug   |
-------------------
| title1 | myslug |
| title2 | myslug |

log
|          path          |
--------------------------
| /article/'myslug'      |
| /article/'unmentioned' |
```

Try out something like the following:

```
select title, count(*) from article a join log l where concat('''', a.slug, '''') = substring(l.path, 10) group by title;
```

For more complex queries it can be helpful to at first write smaller queries which help you to figure out the whole query later. For example just check if the string functions return what you expect:

```
select substring(l.path, 10) from log l;
select concat('''', a.slug, '''') from article a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, this doesn't seem to be part of the SQL standard and only works in some implementations. I updated my answer.

Comment: You miss understood me, I just looked up the standard to see that "string" is not part of it even though it works in some other SQL implementations.

Comment: All you say is right I am sure, but I meant something completely different. Using double quotes as string delimiter works in some SQL implementations but is not part of the standard. Let's not start a lengthy discussion about this.

Comment: I appreciate the help! The schema that you have provided is exactly what I am dealing with ( I would have provided it, but I'm very new at this. ) I did end up solving it from this! Thank you.